# beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm, javabeans

I am trying to run my project, but I get these following exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MY_P_U] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:342)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
at test.Test.main(Test.java:9) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MY_P_U] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:530)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:630)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:339)
... 13 more Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MY_P_U] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:911)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:268)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
... 26 more Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: org.gestion.infopanne.entities.simplemessage column: genre (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:675)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:697)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:719)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:473)
at org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass.validate(SingleTableSubclass.java:65)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1332)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1835)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:902)
... 31 more
```

By the way, I added these dependencies before starting my project :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.FINAL</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.FINAL</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0.FINAL</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.FINAL</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

And finally, my applicationContext.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

<bean id="dao" class="org.gestion.infopanne.dao.FonctionsDAOimplem">  </bean>
<bean id="metier" class="org.gestion.infopanne.metier.Fonctionsmetierimplem">
<property name="dao" ref="dao"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver">   </property>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/panne"> </property>
<property name="username" value="root"></property>
<property name="password" value=""></property>
</bean>
<bean id="persistenceUnitManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitMana ger">
<property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
<list>

<value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
</list>
</property>
<property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager">    </property>
<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MY_P_U"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory">   </property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
```

```
    package org.gestion.infopanne.entities; 
    import java.util.Date; 
    import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue; 
    import javax.persistence.Entity; 

    @Entity 
    @DiscriminatorValue("simple") 
    public class simplemessage extends message{ 

    public simplemessage() { super(); } 

    public simplemessage(String materiel, String description,String genre, String date) 

    { super(materiel, description, genre, date); } 
}
```

Message class:

```
package org.gestion.infopanne.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorColumn;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="genre",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class message implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idm;
private String materiel;
private String description;
private String genre;
private String date;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idm")
private utilisateur user;
public message() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public message(String materiel, String description,String genre, String date) {
    super();
    this.materiel = materiel;
    this.description = description;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.date = date;
}
public int getId() {
    return idm;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.idm = id;
}
public String getMateriel() {
    return materiel;
}
public void setMateriel(String materiel) {
    this.materiel = materiel;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}
public void setGenre(String genre) {
    this.genre = genre;
}
public String getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
public utilisateur getUser() {
    return user;
}
public void setUser(utilisateur user) {
    this.user = user;
}

}
```

Comment: please post the simplemessage entity

Comment: the error says *Repeated column in mapping for entity: org.gestion.infopanne.entities.simplemessage*. Did you have this class? edit your question and add the code of the class simplemessage

Comment: package org.gestion.infopanne.entities;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("simple")

public class simplemessage extends message{

 public simplemessage() {
  super();
 }

 public simplemessage(String materiel, String description,String genre, String date) {
  super(materiel, description, genre, date);
 }

}

Answer (score 1):

According to this 2 links:

http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/jpa-joined-inheritance-jpa-entity-config.html

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance

I think you have to remove this line from the message class:

```
private String genre;
```

and its getter and setter methods, because you just defined this column  with the *DiscriminationColumn* annotation:

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="genre",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `@DiscriminatorColumn` / `@DiscriminatorValue`, you are basically telling JPA that if the column is of such value, then it is of the said type (`SimpleMessage` in this case). So, if you have class of type `SimpleMessage`, then you already know the value of `genre` will be `simple`. Hence you don't need a getter to know what's the value of `genre` column.

But, say for some reason you need that field in the JPA entity, it is required that that field is immutable, i.e. you can't change the value, as changing the value means it's no longer of type `SimpleMessage`, and your code breaks at that point. So to enforce you to make `genre` immutable, you will have to mark it as so, else the entity will be invalid.

So in this case, add the following annotation before the definition of `genre` in `Message` Class

```
@Column(insert="false", update="false")
private String genre;
```